# Identical grid-area names in different grid containers?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

Browsers render the following HTML & CSS as desired, but still my question: is it correct that grid-area names, other than IDs in HTML, don't have to be unique?

```css
body > div {
display: grid;
grid: ". left right ." auto / 1fr 200px 200px 1fr;
background: grey;
margin: 0 0 3px;
}

body > div > div:first-child {
grid-area: left;
background: lightgrey;
}

body > div > div:last-child {
grid-area: right;
background: darkgrey;
}
```

```html
<div>
<div>Left 1</div>
<div>Right 1</div>
</div>

<div>
<div>Left 2</div>
<div>Right 2</div>
</div>
```

Comment: your question is opinion based

Comment: Why? I'm asking if the specification allows the same name for multiple elements, so it's not a matter of opinions.

Comment: Before you edited the question you were asking about best practices, which I imagine is what was seen as opinion-based.

Comment: @EricBln then you have no question because you actually tested and it works, so what kind of answer are you waiting for?

Comment: Some browsers render HTML containing multiple elements with the same ID "correctly", still it's not allowed. So rendering as desired doesn't necessarily mean that the spec allows it.
So my question is: does the spec allow the same grid-area name for multiple items?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The CSS Grid Layout Module Level 1 specification doesn't explicitly mention restrictions on reusing grid area names within a container. **The scoping rules of CSS** apply here – the grid area names are scoped to the grid container in which they are defined. Each grid container creates its own layout context, and grid area names are resolved within that context.

If the specification doesn't explicitly forbid it and browsers handle it well, you have some flexibility, but it's advisable to use unique names for clarity in your code.

Comment: Thank you and you're right about the clarity, but in this case there might be dozens of grid rows getting the same behaviour, so giving each grid item a unique name and declaring each row individually would be redundant in a way.

Comment: @EricBln your consideration is valid. Using identical grid area names across different grid containers is correct and efficient when you want a consistent layout for multiple grid items without redundant CSS declarations.